# Fill out cell in row range where active cell is then set active cell to the next row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an automated Excel file in which it will copy a cell to another. I already did a timer in which it will start and stop. Once it stopped I can now copy it to a specific cell (for example J11), but what I need now is that every time I stop the timer it will copy the time to the next row (J12) and so on and so forth. So every time I stop the timer it will copy the value to the next rowcell.

Here's my code so far.

```
Dim Start As Single, RunTime As Single
Dim ElapsedTime As String



Range("A1").Value = 0
Range("K8").Value = "In Progress"
Range("K8").Interior.Color = 5296274

Start = Timer

Do While Range("A1").Value = 0

DoEvents
RunTime = Timer
ElapsedTime = Format((RunTime - Start) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
Range("C4").Value = ElapsedTime
Application.StatusBar = ElapsedTime

Loop

Range("C4").Value = ElapsedTime
Range("K8").Interior.Color = 192
Range("K8").Value = "Ended"
Application.StatusBar = False

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now) ' wait for 3 seconds

Range("K8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Range("K8").Value = ""
Range("I5").Value = ""
Range("A1").Value = 0
Range("C4").Value = 0

Range("F8").Copy Range("E11")
Range("F9").Copy Range("F11") <---this is static, this is where I want it to be dynamic.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
'Set Active Cell
 eRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


 Cells(eRow, 5).Value = Range("F8").Value
 Cells(eRow, 6).Value = Range("F9").Value
```